# Angular2 - Binding of datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angular, data-binding, datepicker

How do I get the chosen date of input and put the tag `<p>`.

I'm using the jqueryUI datepicker, already I tried to do the binding trying to capture with the change and click events, but did not work.

Can anybody help me?

```
import "rxjs/Rx";
import {Component, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: '<my-evento></my-evento>',
    template: `<input (change)="updateDate($event)" type="text" id="datepicker">
               <p>{{ date }}</p>`
})

export class EventoComponent implements AfterViewInit{
    date: string;

    constructor(){}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
       $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    }

    updateDate($event): void {
        this.date = $event.target.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: you may want to take a look at ngModel  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html

Comment: it only makes the binding when I write in input. `<input [(ngModel)]="date" type="text" id="datepicker">` but when I use the calendar does not do the binding

Comment: Inject in a 'ChangeDetectorRef' https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html  and call either `markForCheck` or `detectChanges` to trigger an update.  Also have a look at the `DoCheck`lifecycle hook https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck which is where you'd make your calls on the `ChangeDetectorRef`

Comment: I have read and tried to do, but this a bit confusing, you could show the code in my example?

Comment: `export class EventoComponent implements AfterViewInit, DoCheck{ constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {} ngDoCheck() { this._cdr.detectChanges(); } }`

Comment: How could not make it work, I changed my strategy and solved my problem using the Calendar component of Primeng library [Primeng - Calendar](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you bind the model like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="date" type="date" id="datepicker">
```

does the compiler tell you that the format has to be in yyyy-dd-mm format?

if so, you may need to use a custom [directive](https://github.com/JohannesHoppe/angular-date-value-accessor) or bind the date field with the date pipe like this:

```
<input [ngModel]="date | date:'y-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="date=$event" type="date" id="datepicker">
```